# Print HTML table in .NET with table header at start of each page

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, printing-web-page

I would like to print an HTML file that I am generating myself, but I want the pages to have the same table header at the start of each page.

I think the best options to print an HTML file is the webbrowser control? but this won't give the table header at the start of each page (and I will have to contend with the ugly file://c:\temp\file.htm at the top of each page etc)

I guess I could use the print document control but I will have to manually add the table lines and work out the padding etc.

Comment: I've never found a good way of doing this. If you know row heights exactly you can manually split the table every X rows then. Do you have to create an HTML page or is PDF an option? I've been using iTextSharp for creating PDFs and after you play with it for a bit its pretty easy to calculate when you need to add a new page and start a new header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a CSS property [page-break-before](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_print_pagebb.asp) that might help you out but it is unreliable within a table so you might have to use a seperate table for each row or use div layers for it to work.

Its not optimal but We used it in one occation.

the principle is that it triggers if the renderer detects that the page break would occur within the element.